# Querying highways with Overpass QL for calculating routes

Tags: overpass-api, graphhopper

I want to query highways with Overpass to calculate routes with Graphhopper. With some trial and error I came to the following query and it seems to work (tested in overpass turbo):

```
(
  ._;
  way[highway]({{bbox}});
  node(w);
);
out;
```

I still have trouble understanding what exactly the query does, especially the default set `._;`. Is it actually redundant here?

Also, I really only need to calculate routes for pedestrians and cyclists. What would be the best approach there? Expanding the query above with filters or just limit the vehicle in Graphhopper?

Comment: ._ is explained in more detail here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Item - it’s not needed in your case. Also add additional tag filters as needed rather than querying for all highways.

Comment: @mmd I read that part, but I still didn't understand how to use `._`. But thanks for confirming that it is redundant in my query.

Comment: There are several examples on how to use `._` on the Overpass QL by Example page: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example - does that help?